# Bedeutung "Schreiben"

Tags: meaning

Wenn in einem Brief in Papierform ein weiteres "Schreiben" angekündigt wird, ist es seitens des Empfängers gerechtfertigt, auch das angekündigte Dokument in Papierform auf dem Postwege zu erwarten, oder kann der Ankündiger davon ausgehen, dass der Empfänger auch mit einer Zustellung auf elektronischem Wege rechnet?
Der Duden definiert das su Substantiv "Schreiben" als "schriftliche Mitteilung meist sachlichen Inhalts, offiziellen Charakters", sagt über den Zustellungsweg nichts aus.
Ist im obigen Beispiel die Papierform impliziert, zumal auch kein alternativer Versandweg angekündigt ist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Höchstwahrscheinlich.

Wie richtig erkannt, gibt der Begriff "Schreiben" keine zwingende Form vor.
Dennoch entspricht es meiner Erwartung/Gewöhnung, dass ohne Verweis auf eine Formänderung beim nächsten Schreiben dieselbe Form gewählt wird. Es muss für einen Formwechsel auch die Adresse der anderen Form bekannt sein.

Daher nur "höchstwahrscheinlich".

Als Beispiel für unerwarteten Wechsel zwischen Bürger und Behörde wäre es unter Umständen möglich, dass zwischen beiden Schreiben plötzlich auf De-Mail ([Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/De-Mail)) gewechselt wird. Weil - rein hypothetisch - der interne Verwaltungsprozess sagt "sobald De-Mail eingerichtet, alles darüber schicken".

Dieser Wechsel konnte & kann vor allem beim [beA(wiki)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Besonderes_elektronisches_Anwaltspostfach) zwischen Anwälten und Gerichten passieren, weil der Einsatz gesetzlich ab geplanten Terminen vorgeschrieben ist - unabhängig davon, ob der Empfänger des Schreibens technisch auch empfangsbereit ist.

Comment: Das hängt sicher auch vom Absender ab. Wenn es sich um eine Behörde handelt, wird die Zustellungsform des weiteren Schreibens "Papier" sein.